# SQL - Most Common Day of Week Query

Tags: sql, date, datepart

I am trying to query on which day of the week most orders occur. I have written a query that returns a result. But, the result is, I believe, the day of the week possibly based on most orders, but the day for every order, so there are dozens. I am wondering how to only return the one day.

The table is:

```
Orders
 OrderID
 OrderDate

SELECT MAX(DAYNAME(OrderDate)) as WeekDay  
FROM Orders O
GROUP BY OrderDate
OrDER BY WeekDay DESC;
```

Comment: what database system are your using? The answer is very dependent on that.

Answer (score 2):

The query you are trying to write is:

```
SELECT TOP (1) DAYNAME(OrderDate) as WeekDay, COUNT(*)
FROM Orders O
GROUP BY DAYNAME(OrderDate)
OrDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Although this query appears to answer your question, you have to be very careful.  After all, if `Orders` had only one day's worth of data, then that day of the week would predominate.  My suggestion would be to take data from a specified number of weeks -- preferably with no holidays -- to get this information.

Your question doesn't specify the database (although I could guess).  The specific date/time logic for this depends on the database.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I am having trouble executing this. It says the 'WITH' is not valid at that point. I haven't used 'WITH' and I'm unfamiliar with its syntax. Would you be able to clarify what it is doing?

Comment: I couldn't your comment to function, but I tried another approach using your ideas:

    `SELECT MAX(DAYNAME(OrderDate)) as WeekDay, COUNT(*)'
    FROM Orders O
    GROUP BY DAYNAME(OrderDate)
    ORDER BY WeekDay DESC;

    SELECT MAX(DAYNAME(OrderDate)) as WeekDay, COUNT(*)
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY DAYNAME(OrderDate)
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1;`

This did return the days of the week with the count and the second query returned the top day with most orders, although both Tuesday and Thursday had the same amount. (Sorry having trouble formatting the code in here)

Comment: The `WITH TIES` is not that important.  It just returns all week days that are highest, if there are ties.

Answer (score 0):

This will let you know how many orders were placed on which day.

```
 SELECT 
    DAYNAME((OrderDate)) AS dayofweek, COUNT(OrderID) AS ordered
FROM
    Orders
GROUP BY dayofweek
ORDER BY ordered DESC;
```